# Storyboard and Container View crazy behaviour

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

I have a little problem that's driving me crazy.
I just started creating a storyboard for a very simple application and running it I can't understand why the storyboard appereance inside Xcode is completely different by the running look.

I suppose that this two images below can explain my issue better than words.

[image: Xcode appearance]
This is the Xcode appearance and what I would like to see on my iPhone screen. All the controller are configured, by default, to infer the size of the parent controller.

[image: running appearance]

This is the running look and it not I supposed to see on the screen.
It's seems like the view of TEST view controller does not infer the size of the tabBarController available size, instead it match the size of the main container view.

Any suggest how to solve this issue, is it maybe a Xcode bug? I'm running the latest Xcode 4.5.2

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure that this behaviour is caused by the new constrains mechanism introduced by Apple on the iOS 6.0 SDK. Finally I found an option for the storyboard file that is "Use Autolayout". Disabling this flag the app visualisation between Xcode and Simulator is now congruent. To be more precise I think that the bug is caused by a miss constraint between the controller view and the UITabBar.

I'm going to notify Apple about this crazy behaviour using his bug report service.

Comment: Where does the iAd come from. It is not visible in the storyboard. I think the view is shifted to make room for the iAd. Remove the iAd and try again. Check the autoresizing masks.

Comment: The problem persist if I remove iAd and use the Container View to full size. The initial View Controller is a simple ViewController containing two views. The first one is an AdBannerView (iAd) and the second one is the Container View that you can see on the storyboard image. The craziness is that if I configure the initial View Controller to UITabBarController everything runs well but if I use the Container View seems like the View of UIViewController inside the UITabBarController does not understand there is the TabBar.

Comment: Have you tried to set the size of the view?

Comment: It does not work. I can see the setted frame size of the view (configured in viewDidLoad) on the log but the view is still at full screen size.

Comment: What is the autoresizing mask of the view?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 developing for iOS 6.0 so there is no aututoresizing mask but instead I'm using the constrains automatically configured by Xcode.

Comment: What is the segue between the ad controller and the tab bar controller ? Replace ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the tabbar as the storyboard's initial view controller on an iPhone device. Do not add it as childViewController. Then add the iAd to a SuperViewController, which would be superclass of the tabbar's view controllers. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Any reason to avoid tabBarController insertion as childViewController? Maybe I miss some documentation.
I'll try it as soon as I can.

Comment: You`re welcome. My guess is, that is the reason for the view to be shifted. According to Apple`s [View Controller Catalog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3) you should use the Tab Bar Controller as root VC or present it modally on an iPhone device. You can show it in a popover or in a split VC pane if you are building the app for iPad.